# Dropdown within link environment does not work

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, href

I'm trying to put a dropdown select menu inside a link environment:
(Also I read that as of HTML5, it's okay to put "a" environments around divs. Any thoughts?)

```
            <a href="">
                <div id="foo">
                    <select>
                        <option value="a">Stuff</option>
                        <option value="b">More stuff</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </a>
```

Anyway, at least in Chrome this does not work correctly: If I open the menu, the link environment is clicked and the page refreshes. In IE, this does work as I want it to. I tried z-index, but this does not work for Chrome.

Thanks in advance,

Lennart

Comment: You should putting an input element inside of an anchor, it will be buggy when you click it for it to dropdown as you have found out

Comment: Then I guess http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/ is not a robust solution. Thank you.

Comment: You can wrap a div but don't do it blindly. You have a select in there, if you just have text and images, it will work fine

Comment: As per W3C validation - u cannot use a DIV tag inside an anchor element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods, both are pretty simple.

1. Take away the `href=""` part of the `<a>` element. That's what's sending the postback request and refreshing the page.
2. If you want to keep the link for whatever reason. Make the click event return false. Add this to the `<a>` tag: `onclick="return false;"`.

Like so:

```html
<a href="" onclick="return false;">
  <div id="foo">
    <select>
      <option value="a">Stuff</option>
      <option value="b">More stuff</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</a>
```

If you want to automate the second method, you can add some javascript:

```js
var dropdownlink = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < dropdownlink.length; i++) {
  if (dropdownlink[i].getElementsByTagName("select").length > 0) {
    dropdownlink[i].onclick = function() {
      return false;
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="k">
  <div id="foo">
    <select>
      <option value="a">Stuff</option>
      <option value="b">More stuff</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="">Test Link</a>
```

Comment: Yes, but it ultimately needs to refer to something. What I'd like is that clicking the dropdown does not trigger the anchor at all :)

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg Sorry about that. I've updated my answer with another method to keep the link.